# Italicizing just one part of a legend label in R in ggplot line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, typography

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEpnz.png)

I would like to just italicize the label 'NA' on the legend of this graph, on ggplot in R.

Everything I've tried so far has just italicized the entire legend text, instead of specifically just 'NA'.
Scale_fill_discrete does not alter my legend, I think because the graph uses geom_line and geom_point as opposed to geom_bar/geom_col.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As a quick note - using the same principles in the linked questions but putting them in `scale_colour_discrete` will do the same job. It can be helpful if in stackoverflow questions you put the code you use in the question so that answers can pinpoint how to solve your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some ideas!